# why can't asp.net find my textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-controls

I'm trying to add more fields to the `CreateUserWizardStep`, here is what I added:

```
<asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    <asp:Label ID="NickNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="NickName">Nick Name:</asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="NickName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="NickName"
                        ErrorMessage="Nick Name is required." ToolTip="Nick Name is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <%-- The default code is left unchanged, but not shown here --%>
        </table>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
```

Then I tried to reference the objects like this

```
protected void NewUserWizard_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateUserWizardStep step = NewUserWizard.FindControl("CreateUserWizardStep1") as CreateUserWizardStep;
    TextBox nickName = step.FindControl("NickName") as TextBox;
    // insert additional information to the database
}
```

The problem is, I'm getting nulls for `nickName`. Am I using `FindControl("")` incorrectly?

Comment: Why not just refer to them as this.NickName or this.CreateWizardSTep1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may want to use a recursive find control function such as here: http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/recursive-findcontrol/

Comment: thanks, the link explain a lot, but is it the only way to get that control of mine? It's kind of ridiculous to write new code myself just to get a simple control

Comment: @phunehehe - yes. this is the only way.

Answer (score 2):

[`FindControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol.aspx) only

> Searches the current naming container for the specified server control.

i.e. It only checks the current containers *direct* children.

You can use the [`Controls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.controls(v=VS.100).aspx) property to return all the children of `step`:

```
ControlCollection children = step.Controls;
```

and enumerate over this looking for your text box.

Comment: @ChrisF: notice that the table is not the naming container for the TextBox, it's not a web control.

Comment: Thanks, I saw the documentation already, but don't understand what `current naming container` means. And worse, `TextBox nickName = FindControl("NickName") as TextBox;` didn't work either :(

Comment: @phunehehe - "current naming container" in this case means `step`. @Claudio has a point about the table not being a web control, but there's still a level of indirection.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the control myself, but doesn't *CreateUserWizardStep1.NickNameLabel* work?